Anything-llm from docker and docker-compose.yml
I am trying to execute anything-llm from docker and I am trying to create a docker-compose.yml file, becuase I want it to execute more than 1 container.
In the respository of anything.llm it shows how to execute from docker and it works well from me.
export STORAGE_LOCATION=$HOME/anythingllm && \
mkdir -p $STORAGE_LOCATION && \
touch "$STORAGE_LOCATION/.env" && \
docker run -d -p 3001:3001 \
--cap-add SYS_ADMIN \
-v ${STORAGE_LOCATION}:/app/server/storage \
-v ${STORAGE_LOCATION}/.env:/app/server/.env \
-e STORAGE_DIR="/app/server/storage" \
mintplexlabs/anythingllm

But like a said before, I want it to create a docker-compose.yml file to execute multiple containers with just one file. This is my docker-compose.yml code:
services:
  anythingllm:
    image: mintplexlabs/anythingllm
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
    volumes:
      - ${STORAGE_LOCATION}:/app/server/storage
      - ${STORAGE_LOCATION}/.env:/app/server/.env
    environment:
      - STORAGE_DIR=/app/server/storage
    command: /bin/sh -c "mkdir -p $STORAGE_LOCATION && touch \"$STORAGE_LOCATION/.env\" && npm start"

It download the image, create the container, also create the STORAGE_LOCATION directory and the .env file. But when is going to start the container I got the following error:
container init: error mounting "/run/desktop/mnt/host/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-22.04/..."

Of course is going to return an error because inside of /run/ I don't have the desktop directory.
I am trying to execute anything-llm from docker and I am trying to create a docker-compose.yml file, becuase I want it to execute more than 1 container.
In the respository of anything.llm it shows how to execute from docker and it works well from me.
export STORAGE_LOCATION=$HOME/anythingllm && \
mkdir -p $STORAGE_LOCATION && \
touch "$STORAGE_LOCATION/.env" && \
docker run -d -p 3001:3001 \
--cap-add SYS_ADMIN \
-v ${STORAGE_LOCATION}:/app/server/storage \
-v ${STORAGE_LOCATION}/.env:/app/server/.env \
-e STORAGE_DIR="/app/server/storage" \
mintplexlabs/anythingllm

But like a said before, I want it to create a docker-compose.yml file to execute multiple containers with just one file. This is my docker-compose.yml code:
services:
  anythingllm:
    image: mintplexlabs/anythingllm
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
    volumes:
      - ${STORAGE_LOCATION}:/app/server/storage
      - ${STORAGE_LOCATION}/.env:/app/server/.env
    environment:
      - STORAGE_DIR=/app/server/storage
    command: /bin/sh -c "mkdir -p $STORAGE_LOCATION && touch \"$STORAGE_LOCATION/.env\" && npm start"

It download the image, create the container, also create the STORAGE_LOCATION directory and the .env file. But when is going to start the container I got the following error:
container init: error mounting "/run/desktop/mnt/host/wsl/docker-desktop-bind-mounts/Ubuntu-22.04/..."

Of course is going to return an error because inside of /run/ I don't have the desktop directory.
I found a few things:

If I execute first, the command:

export STORAGE_LOCATION=$HOME/anythingllm && \
mkdir -p $STORAGE_LOCATION && \
touch "$STORAGE_LOCATION/.env" && \
docker run -d -p 3001:3001 \
--cap-add SYS_ADMIN \
-v ${STORAGE_LOCATION}:/app/server/storage \
-v ${STORAGE_LOCATION}/.env:/app/server/.env \
-e STORAGE_DIR="/app/server/storage" \
mintplexlabs/anythingllm

And then stop the container and executed the docker-compose.yml file it start the container without any error.

I tried replacing the variable in the docker-compose.yml with the directory like: /home/user/anythingllm, but still I am getting the error when is executed for the first time.

What do I need to change to the docker-compose.yml file works fine without executing the raw command from the terminal?

what content is .env
I got error, unable to open database file ../storage/anythingllm.db

Same issue for me. Have you resolved it? I guess it is related to the UID/GID.

The issue was in the last line on the docker-compose.yml file.
For some reason the touch \"$STORAGE_LOCATION/.env\" was not creating a .env file but it was creating a .env folder. So I decided to create it manually and now create and execute it correctly.

Ok, now it works. But, can you try  touch "$STORAGE_LOCATION".env ?
